# What is the difference in these calls to Perl's print?

Tags: perl

Where is the difference between the following two Statements?

`print "surname=" ,$myVal, "\n";`

and

`print "surname=" .$myVal. "\n"`

I've tested them and both return the same result. Is there even a difference?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Perl programmer would probably write that as:

```
print "surname=$myVal\n";
```

It does look like it's doing the same thing, doesn't it? And in your example it does do the same thing. The difference is more obvious if you replace the scalar variable with an array.

```
my @var = qw(some data);

print "value=", @var, "\n";
print "value=". @var. "\n";
```

The difference is in the number of arguments that are passed to the print function. If you use the concatenation operator (.) then your arguments are concatenated together into one string and print gets a single argument. If you use the comma, then print gets a list of arguments.

Of course, it's possible to mix the methods in the same print call.

```
print "surname=" ,$myVal . "\n";
```

Another nice example is to use the return value from localtime.

```
print 'The time is ', localtime, "\n";
print 'The time is '. localtime, "\n";
```

Answer (score 8):

The former will print each item in the list separated with `$,`. The latter joins everything first so there isn't anything to separate. Unless `$,` has something printable in it, there is no significant difference between the statements.

Answer (score 5):

print can accept a list, which is what you are passing it. Print will just do it's thing (i.e output) on everything in the list, which is `surname=`, `$myVal`, and a `\n`

The second example has to concat everything first, and then print it.

The use of Commas do not concat, which is also a distinction between the two.

Answer (score 2):

As people has stated before, `.` concatenate the strings and `,`  separate array elements.

One thing to take into account with the `.` form is the performance issues in some very specific scenarios due to memory management: the `.` version needs to create the new string first in memory and keep expanding the addressed memory (could someone elaborate a bit more in this part?). If you were printing this in a loop 1 million of times with thousand of concatenations of very large strings the `.` version would give you very poor performance vs the `,` version. Is like slurping a whole file into memory vs processing line by line. But mere mortals will not notice this issue in the day to day life with modern computers.

Answer (score 1):

as far as I know `print` can take a list as well, which I think is the case with the first piece of code (comma delimited). The second ( with '.'s)  is just string appending, in other words the first call sends three arguments to print while the second sends one.

edit: here's the [documentation page](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html)